# Getting line mouse is on tkinter text

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-text

I am trying to make a sidebar for a tkinter Text widget that displays a red dot next to the line that the mouse hovers over. Currently it is configured to go to the selected line but would be better if it tracked the mouse. I know how to track the mouses y position with `root.winfo_pointery()` but don't know how the get the corresponding line for that. I also don't want it to display anything if it is out of the text widget's y area or if there is no line. How do I cross compare the y value of the pointer to text lines?

Current code:

```
from tkinter import *
class BreakpointBar(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Initializes the canvas
        Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs, highlightthickness=0)
        self.textwidget = None
        self.ovals = []

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        #Attaches the canvas to the text widget
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        #Redraws the canvas
        """redraw line numbers"""
        # try:
        self.delete("all")
        self.unbind_all("<Enter>")
        self.unbind_all("<Leave>")
        self.ovals = []
        index = self.textwidget.index("insert")
        index_linenum = str(index).split(".")[0]


        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        print(self.winfo_pointerx())
        print(self.winfo_pointery())
        while True :
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            if linenum == index_linenum:
                oval = self.create_oval(5, y, 15, y+10, fill="red", outline="red")
                self.tag_bind(oval, "<Enter>", lambda event: self.on_enter(event, oval))
                self.tag_bind(oval, "<Leave>", lambda event: self.on_exit(event, oval))
                self.tag_bind(oval, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.on_press(event, oval))
                self.ovals.append(oval)
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)
        # except:
        #     pass

    def on_enter(self, event, oval):
        self.itemconfig(oval, fill="dark red", outline="dark red")


    def on_exit(self, event, oval):
        self.itemconfig(oval, fill="red", outline="red")

    def on_press(self, event, oval):
        index_linenum = int(str(self.textwidget.index("insert")).split(".")[0])
        self.textwidget.insert("{}.end".format(index_linenum), "\nbreakpoint\n")
        self.textwidget.mark_set("insert", "{}.0".format(index_linenum+2))
        self.textwidget.see("insert")
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
text=Text(frame)
text.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
bb = BreakpointBar(frame, width=20)
bb.attach(text)
bb.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
root.bind("<Button-1>", bb.redraw)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", bb.redraw)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index for character nearest to the mouse via an x,y coordinate using the format `@x,y`.

For example, if you have a function bound to the `<Motion>` event, you can get the index under the cursor by doing something like this:

```
def track_mouse(event):
    index = event.widget.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
    ...
```

In the above example, `index` will be in the canonical form of a string in the format *line.character*.

It's important to note that you must give coordinates that are relative to the upper-left corner of the text widget itself, not of the window or display as a whole.

Comment: that returned a blank value

Comment: @TRCK: if that's true, you probably gave it coordinates that was outside of the widget, or your widget is empty. It absolutely will work when  you give it correct data. This has been part of tk for decades. The coordinates have to be relative to the text widget, not the window or the display as a whole.

Comment: I just got it to work!